# How can I append additional text to msg.payload when using the Join node in Node-RED

Tags: node-red

Help with NodeRed - using the Join node to create one msg.payload

Hello!

I’m having issues, specifically with creating a proper msg.payload to send to the two output nodes I'm using (Home Assistant's call service, and the TTS-Ultimate node) I'm using the join node to send the friendly name of a Home Assistant device outbound, but I want additional text appended.

For example, right now I can successfully output the string "Front Door Sensor" with the code's msg.payload below.

What I would like is for the msg.payload to be "Front Door Sensor has been opened for 15 seconds"

I feel it is something simple, yet I can’t figure it out.

P.S. I know I don’t have a connector to the TTS-Ultimate node (since it is broken). You can see the hammer/nail approach I'm taking by looking at the Karson's iPhone Call service node :)

Thank you to anyone in advance for their help here!

```
[
    {
        "id": "fad2d312d08edc5d",
        "type": "server-state-changed",
        "z": "fb106f0953c589ab",
        "name": "Indoor Swing Sensors",
        "server": "e204944a.31bc78",
        "version": 4,
        "exposeToHomeAssistant": false,
        "haConfig": [
            {
                "property": "name",
                "value": ""
            },
            {
                "property": "icon",
                "value": ""
            }
        ],
        "entityidfilter": "binary_sensor.swing_indoor_sensors_only",
        "entityidfiltertype": "exact",
        "outputinitially": true,
        "state_type": "str",
        "haltifstate": "",
        "halt_if_type": "str",
        "halt_if_compare": "is",
        "outputs": 1,
        "output_only_on_state_change": true,
        "for": 0,
        "forType": "num",
        "forUnits": "minutes",
        "ignorePrevStateNull": false,
        "ignorePrevStateUnknown": false,
        "ignorePrevStateUnavailable": false,
        "ignoreCurrentStateUnknown": false,
        "ignoreCurrentStateUnavailable": false,
        "outputProperties": [
            {
                "property": "payload",
                "propertyType": "msg",
                "value": "",
                "valueType": "entityState"
            },
            {
                "property": "data",
                "propertyType": "msg",
                "value": "",
                "valueType": "eventData"
            },
            {
                "property": "topic",
                "propertyType": "msg",
                "value": "",
                "valueType": "triggerId"
            }
        ],
        "x": 580,
        "y": 400,
        "wires": [
            [
                "8abce97126b545bb"
            ]
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": "10b897c87fc08701",
        "type": "api-current-state",
        "z": "fb106f0953c589ab",
        "name": "Home?",
        "server": "e204944a.31bc78",
        "version": 3,
        "outputs": 2,
        "halt_if": "home",
        "halt_if_type": "str",
        "halt_if_compare": "is",
        "entity_id": "group.presence_home",
        "state_type": "str",
        "blockInputOverrides": false,
        "outputProperties": [
            {
                "property": "payload",
                "propertyType": "msg",
                "value": "",
                "valueType": "entityState"
            },
            {
                "property": "data",
                "propertyType": "msg",
                "value": "",
                "valueType": "entity"
            }
        ],
        "for": 0,
        "forType": "num",
        "forUnits": "minutes",
        "override_topic": false,
        "state_location": "payload",
        "override_payload": "msg",
        "entity_location": "data",
        "override_data": "msg",
        "x": 1010,
        "y": 440,
        "wires": [
            [
                "ad751533e42451a4"
            ],
            []
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": "8abce97126b545bb",
        "type": "switch",
        "z": "fb106f0953c589ab",
        "name": "On/Off",
        "property": "payload",
        "propertyType": "msg",
        "rules": [
            {
                "t": "eq",
                "v": "off",
                "vt": "str"
            },
            {
                "t": "eq",
                "v": "on",
                "vt": "str"
            }
        ],
        "checkall": "true",
        "repair": false,
        "outputs": 2,
        "x": 790,
        "y": 400,
        "wires": [
            [
                "59daab0a9c2e91df"
            ],
            [
                "10b897c87fc08701"
            ]
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": "ad751533e42451a4",
        "type": "stoptimer",
        "z": "fb106f0953c589ab",
        "duration": "15",
        "units": "Second",
        "payloadtype": "num",
        "payloadval": "0",
        "name": "",
        "x": 1400,
        "y": 380,
        "wires": [
            [
                "456b4c6727787658"
            ],
            []
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": "f176046f69d4a67c",
        "type": "api-call-service",
        "z": "fb106f0953c589ab",
        "name": "Notify Karson's Phone",
        "server": "e204944a.31bc78",
        "version": 5,
        "debugenabled": true,
        "domain": "notify",
        "service": "mobile_app_karsons_iphone",
        "areaId": [],
        "deviceId": [],
        "entityId": [],
        "data": "{\"message\":\"{{payload}} was left open for more than 15 seconds. Save Mr. Kitty!!\"}",
        "dataType": "json",
        "mergeContext": "",
        "mustacheAltTags": false,
        "outputProperties": [
            {
                "property": "payload",
                "propertyType": "msg",
                "value": "{{payload}} was left open for more than 15 seconds. Save Mr. Kitty!!\"",
                "valueType": "str"
            }
        ],
        "queue": "none",
        "x": 2020,
        "y": 320,
        "wires": [
            []
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": "438edab5f2ca3b45",
        "type": "api-call-service",
        "z": "fb106f0953c589ab",
        "name": "Notify Amy's Phone",
        "server": "e204944a.31bc78",
        "version": 5,
        "debugenabled": true,
        "domain": "notify",
        "service": "mobile_app_amys_iphone",
        "areaId": [],
        "deviceId": [],
        "entityId": [],
        "data": "{\"message\":\"{{payload}} was left open for more than 15 seconds. Save Mr. Kitty!!\"}",
        "dataType": "json",
        "mergeContext": "",
        "mustacheAltTags": false,
        "outputProperties": [],
        "queue": "none",
        "x": 2010,
        "y": 380,
        "wires": [
            []
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": "172f16309f8ac6ad",
        "type": "ttsultimate",
        "z": "fb106f0953c589ab",
        "name": "",
        "voice": "en-US",
        "ssml": false,
        "sonosipaddress": "10.10.100.32",
        "sonosvolume": "40",
        "sonoshailing": "Hailing_Hailing.mp3",
        "config": "a585de9c1021e86d",
        "property": "payload",
        "propertyType": {},
        "rules": [
            {
                "host": "10.10.100.135",
                "hostVolumeAdjust": "0"
            },
            {
                "host": "10.10.100.196",
                "hostVolumeAdjust": "0"
            },
            {
                "host": "10.10.100.177",
                "hostVolumeAdjust": "0"
            },
            {
                "host": "10.10.100.198",
                "hostVolumeAdjust": "0"
            },
            {
                "host": "10.10.100.176",
                "hostVolumeAdjust": "0"
            },
            {
                "host": "10.10.100.160",
                "hostVolumeAdjust": "0"
            }
        ],
        "playertype": "sonos",
        "speakingrate": "1",
        "speakingpitch": "0",
        "unmuteIfMuted": true,
        "x": 1990,
        "y": 260,
        "wires": [
            [],
            []
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": "59daab0a9c2e91df",
        "type": "change",
        "z": "fb106f0953c589ab",
        "name": "Stop Timer",
        "rules": [
            {
                "t": "set",
                "p": "payload",
                "pt": "msg",
                "to": "stop",
                "tot": "str"
            }
        ],
        "action": "",
        "property": "",
        "from": "",
        "to": "",
        "reg": false,
        "x": 1030,
        "y": 380,
        "wires": [
            [
                "ad751533e42451a4"
            ]
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": "456b4c6727787658",
        "type": "ha-get-entities",
        "z": "fb106f0953c589ab",
        "name": "Which Sensors?",
        "server": "e204944a.31bc78",
        "version": 0,
        "rules": [
            {
                "property": "entity_id",
                "logic": "in_group",
                "value": "binary_sensor.swing_indoor_sensors_only",
                "valueType": "str"
            },
            {
                "property": "state",
                "logic": "includes",
                "value": "on",
                "valueType": "str"
            }
        ],
        "output_type": "split",
        "output_empty_results": false,
        "output_location_type": "msg",
        "output_location": "payload",
        "output_results_count": 1,
        "x": 1560,
        "y": 460,
        "wires": [
            [
                "3ff8effe4570d0ad"
            ]
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": "3ff8effe4570d0ad",
        "type": "template",
        "z": "fb106f0953c589ab",
        "name": "Format Msg",
        "field": "payload",
        "fieldType": "msg",
        "format": "handlebars",
        "syntax": "mustache",
        "template": "{{payload.attributes.friendly_name}}",
        "output": "str",
        "x": 1580,
        "y": 540,
        "wires": [
            [
                "b34caa7951060775"
            ]
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": "b34caa7951060775",
        "type": "join",
        "z": "fb106f0953c589ab",
        "name": "",
        "mode": "custom",
        "build": "string",
        "property": "payload",
        "propertyType": "msg",
        "key": "topic",
        "joiner": ", ",
        "joinerType": "str",
        "accumulate": false,
        "timeout": "",
        "count": "",
        "reduceRight": false,
        "reduceExp": "",
        "reduceInit": "",
        "reduceInitType": "",
        "reduceFixup": "",
        "x": 1800,
        "y": 540,
        "wires": [
            [
                "f176046f69d4a67c",
                "438edab5f2ca3b45"
            ]
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": "e204944a.31bc78",
        "type": "server",
        "name": "Home Assistant",
        "version": 5,
        "addon": false,
        "rejectUnauthorizedCerts": false,
        "ha_boolean": "y|yes|true|on|home|open",
        "connectionDelay": true,
        "cacheJson": true,
        "heartbeat": false,
        "heartbeatInterval": "30",
        "areaSelector": "friendlyName",
        "deviceSelector": "friendlyName",
        "entitySelector": "friendlyName",
        "statusSeparator": "at: ",
        "statusYear": "hidden",
        "statusMonth": "short",
        "statusDay": "numeric",
        "statusHourCycle": "h23",
        "statusTimeFormat": "h:m",
        "enableGlobalContextStore": true
    },
    {
        "id": "a585de9c1021e86d",
        "type": "ttsultimate-config",
        "name": "TTS Service",
        "noderedipaddress": "10.10.100.3",
        "noderedport": "1980",
        "purgediratrestart": "purge",
        "ttsservice": "googletranslate"
    }
]
```

Comment: I'm still struggling with this, and hopeful that someone has some advice?